# Two List in one datagridview in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

I Just want to know if there's any possibility of displaying 2 query results in 1 datagridview in vb.net just like how the SQL Server Management Studio display the results if there are multiple select() in one execution.

[SSMS Displays 2 grids in 2 Select() Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6NXs.png)

In my form, I have a richtextbox to input the query, one button to execute the query entered in richtextbox and one datagridview where the result will be shown. As I clicked the execute button, only the  result of `SELECT * FROM NameAndAge` was displayed.

[My Created form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ5Jq.png)

Thank you so much :)

P.S.: Sorry for the wrong grammar

Comment: Yes it's possible, have you tried implementing it? Share your [mcve] and tell us what is it you are struggling with.

Comment: But SSMS doesn't display multiple query results in one grid. It displays multiple grids; one for each result set. If you call `Fill` on a data adapter and p[ass a `DataSet` then the `Tables.Count` property will tell you how many grids to create.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response, as you requested, I edited my post.